# How to install libaacs to play Bluray macOS 11?

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib

How can I install libaacs correctly so that VLC 3.0.12 and IINA 1.2.0 can play my Bluray disc?

Is there an easy way on macOS 11 (Big Sur) that works right away? I tried to install libaacs via Homebrew (`brew install libaacs`). but the playback does not work. Example in VLC 3.0.12 it said: Blu-ray error No valid host certificate found in AACS config file.

I think libaacs is not installed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Is there a ready and updated dylib file of libaacs that works immediately?

Answer (score 1):

libaacs is probably installed correctly, assuming there were no install errors. Did you place a current version of KEYDB.cfg in "~/.config/aacs/"?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29807146)